# Detecting the type of data we have

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am importing a csv file into python. As expected, it creates lists with every value as a string, however I want to avoid this. Is there a way for python to detect that a value is actually an int even though it looks like this '24'?

Thank you.

Comment: What library are you using? what does your data look like? You have to give more details

Comment: what if some column contains sometimes a string and sometimes an int in a string? you have to be more specific: show us the code.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to write a function something like this to do the job.
You can expand it to cover other data type.

```
def return_str_type(str):
    possible_type = [int, float]
    for dtype in possible_type:
        try:
            str = dtype(str)
            break   
        except:
            pass
    return type(str).__name__

print(return_str_type('4'))
print(return_str_type('4.3'))
print(return_str_type('s4'))
```

This will give **OP**

```
int
float
str
```

Though you will have to be careful with the order. e.g. `int` check should always be before `float`.

Comment: you don't need eval for this, make a list with the classes and do `str=dtype(str)`

Comment: updated as per you suggestion @Copperfield

Comment: You beat me to it.  I had the same except the function excepted a complete row and returned a list of converted items.  Used with ```data = map(f, csv.reader)```

Comment: @saurabhbaid I think you're onto something! I managed to get a whole list of str and int. Thanks so much!

Comment: As your example shows, there's a built-in type name `str`, so it's best to avoid defining your own variable, arguments, etc, the same.

Answer (score 0):

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) is what you seek.

```
print ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3]') == [1, 2, 3]
print ast.literal_eval('23') == 23
```

Python also has an `eval` command, however it is not safe because non-datatype commands can also be processed for harmful purposes through this function.

Comment: Thank you, I've given it a go and it says Value error: Malformed string but I'll keep trying.

Answer (score -1):

A number of various modules supports this, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) among them. `read_csv` can infer the data types.